# The dimension of simple $\mathbb{R}[x]$-module $M$

Tags: linear-algebra

Since $M$ is simple, $M\cong\mathbb{R}[x]/(p(x))$ for irreducible $p(x)$. We have $p\cdot m=0$ for all $m\in M$.

I tried to find $a,b\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ s.t. $am_1+bm_2=0$ for all $m_1,m_2\in M$ to show that $\dim M=1$, but it didn't work.

How should I approach? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\Bbb R$-dimension of $\Bbb R[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is equal to the degree of $p(x)$, with canonical basis given by the cosets of $1,x,\ldots,x^{n-1}$, where $n$ is the degree of $p(x)$.

What are the possible values of $n$? How to prove?

If $z=a+ib$ is a zero of $p(x)$, then $z'=a-ib$ is a zero of $p(x)$ (check!). Thus $(x-z)(x-z')$ divides $p(x)$. But $d(x) = (x-z)(x-z') = x^2 -2zz'x+ zz'$ is real-valued (check!).
Thus if $p(x)$ is irreducible, then $p(x)=d(x)$. Hence the degree of $p(x)$ is either 1 (if $z=z'$) or 2 (if $z\ne z'$).

Comment: But how do I prove that $\dim M=1$ or $2$?

Comment: What are the possible degrees of irreducible polynomials over the reals?

Comment: $1$ and $x$? Maybe?

Comment: Just one or two.

Comment: Just one more thing, both $p(x)=x$ and $p(x)=x^2+1$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. How do we know what to mod? $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x)$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ are not isomorphic, yet both $(x)$ and $(x^2+1)$ are maximal, arn't they?

Comment: If they are isomorphic, the corresponding vector spaces should be isomorphic. But they are not, since they have different dimension.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are using the word "dimension" ambigously.

The quotient $F[x]/(p(x))$ ($F$ any field) has *two* structures of module:

- it is a $F$-module (i.e. a vector space over $F$) via scalar multiplication. Then its dimension is $\deg(p(x))-1$ because you can use euclidean division to show that classes in $F[x]/(p(x))$ are uniquely represented by polynomials of degree $\leq\deg(p(x))-1$.
- it is a $F[x]$-module via standard multiplication of polynomials (in fact every quotient $A/I$ where $A$ is a ring and $I$ an ideal is an $A$-module naturally), but in this case you cannot talk of dimension because $F[x]$ is **not** a field.
  In fact, excluding trivial cases, as a $F[x]$-module the quotient $F[x]/(p(x))$ is not even free, it is torsion, and does not have a basis. All you can say if that there is a (tautological) short exact sequence
  $$
  0\rightarrow (p(x))\rightarrow F[x]\rightarrow F[x]/(p(x))\rightarrow 0
  $$
  which happens to be its free resolution (both $(p(x))$ and $F[x]$ are free of rank 1). This extends verbatim to all quotients $A/I$ where $A$ is a PID. For more general rings $A$ you still have the exact sequence
  $$
  0\rightarrow I\rightarrow A\rightarrow A/I\rightarrow 0
  $$
  but in general you cannot expect the ideal $I$ to be a free $A$-module.